# Replacing Colspan = "2" with Colspan = "4" using Jquery

Tags: jquery

**VenueID:**
                    
                    
                            3

I want to replace first Colspan="2" with Colspan="4" in my first TR not in complete page using JQuery.

Thanks.

Best Regards,
MS

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This jQuery should handle the condition of finding a td with colspan 2 in the first tr of any table and set its colspan to 4.

```
$("table tr:first td[colspan=2]").attr('colspan',4);
```

The better thing to do would be to just fix your HTML to produce colspan=4

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you forgot to close one of your `<tr>`'s. Second, you'll need a unique id or classname attached to that `<td>` to target it more easily. Third, use JQuery [`attr()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/attr) method. Like this:

```
<tr>
     <td colspan="2" id="thatsmytd"></td>
</tr>

$('#thatsmytd').attr('colspan','4');
```

Comment: Sorry But I can't have id as it generated at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Use :first selector:

```
$("table tr:first")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("table tr:first").attr('colspan','4');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("table[id$=FormView1] tr:first td[colspan=2]").attr("colspan", "4");
```

Answer (score 0):

n1313's solution to changing the attribute is correct. If your question is how do you select the first row of a page that contains a cell with a colspan attribute then you just need to change your selector to something like this:

```
$("tr:first").find("td[colspan='2']:first").attr('colspan','4');
```

This is very specific.  You may need to play with it to work exactly the way you need.