# How to replace value in td using jquery/php? （wordpress）

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, html-table

I have a html code below (created using a plugin). 
I need to change colspan="6" to colspan="4". 
I tried jQuery below, but it doesn't work...
Would you please help me?

```
<table class="shop_table">
   <thead>
       <tr><th></tr></th>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr><td class="aa"></td></tr>
    <tr><td class="bb"></td></tr>
    <tr><td class="cc" colspan="6"></td></tr>
   <tbody>
</table>
```

```
$('.shop_table').find('td:last-child').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType===3;
}).remove().end().end().find('colspan="6"').replaceWith($(('colspan="4"'));
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the selector `[colspan="6"]` you can get to each and set a new attribute:

```js
$('.shop_table [colspan="6"]').each(function() {
  this.setAttribute('colspan', '4');
});
console.log($('table').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="shop_table">
   <thead>
       <tr><th></th></tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr class="aa"><td></td></tr>
    <tr class="bb"><td></td></tr>
    <tr class="cc" colspan="6"><td></td></tr>
   <tbody>
</table>
```

Or, without jQuery:

```js
for (const elm of document.querySelectorAll('.shop_table [colspan="6"]')) {
  elm.setAttribute('colspan', '4');
}
console.log(document.querySelector('table').innerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="shop_table">
   <thead>
       <tr><th></th></tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr class="aa"><td></td></tr>
    <tr class="bb"><td></td></tr>
    <tr class="cc" colspan="6"><td></td></tr>
   <tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help. I copy & pasted the code but it doesn't work for me. I'm a complete beginner I'm sorry but would you please let me know why? https://i.imgur.com/ff8eN8u.jpg

Comment: It works just fine here - press "Run code snippet" and you'll see it replacing the attribute as desired. If that's not enough, please edit a [MCVE] into the question demonstrating the problem

Comment: Would it be becaue of console.log($('table').html());? My page is not .html it's .php .. I'm not sure...

Comment: The `console.log($('table').html());` is only there in the live snippet to demonstrate that the code is working as desired. You can remove it in your actual code. But no, the extension of the page you're on will not have anything to do with this.

Comment: Oh.. I see. Thank you. I deleted it and tried to run it. It shows the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" .. I'm not sure what it means.. I'm sorry to bother you but could you hlep me?

Comment: Sounds like you do not have jQuery installed on the page... you can do it without jQuery easily, see new snippet in answer

Comment: So did you try it? You can also try using `jQuery` instead of `$`

Comment: Oh, Thanks a lot for your help. Now it works, yeah, when I change it to jQuery it works. I learnt a lot from you. Thank you again : )

Comment: Oh, okay, I did it. Thank you for letting me know how to use this platform. You are the best. And, I upvoted and it says 'Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.' Thank you again : )

Comment: Be aware that 'colspan' attribute belongs only to td elements. In the HTML example you provided you have assigned 'colspan' attribute to a tr element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `prop()` or `attr()` and both methods will loop through all of them

```js
$('.shop_table td[colspan="6"]').prop('colSpan', 4)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="shop_table" border=1>
   <thead>
       <tr><th>111</th><th>111</th><th>111</th><th>111</th><th>111</th><th>111</th><th>111</th></tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr><td class="aa">222</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="bb">333</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="cc" colspan="6">444</td></tr>
     <tr><td class="aa">222</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="bb">333</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="cc" colspan="6">444</td></tr>
   <tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey a simple answer to your question is this:

`$("table tr:last td[colspan=6]").attr('colspan',4);`

I select the Table, then the last TR, and then the TD representing the one you want to be changed.

Then I add the attribute colspan 4.

This is a codepen showing it working: https://codepen.io/SweetChillyPhilly/pen/MWJbBPo

And here is the SO question where you can read more about how this solution became to be
[Replacing Colspan = "2" with Colspan = "4" using Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393901/replacing-colspan-2-with-colspan-4-using-jquery)

Comment: Happy to help, dont forget to upvote when you can!

Comment: I upvoted and it shows "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: ill help you out. Enjoy